# Using an assembly function in a C program

Tags: c, assembly, dos

im having a small issue with my assembly function that i made.

```
;  Im failing super hard at writing this
;  Function.

.MODEL c, small
    .DATA?
    .DATA
curpos_ PROTO C columns_:BYTE, rows_:BYTE
    .CODE
public curpos_
curpos_ PROC  C columns_:BYTE, rows_:BYTE
    mov dh, columns_
    mov dl, rows_
    mov     bh, 0
    mov     ah, 2
    int 10h
    ret
curpos_ ENDP
END
```

And my C file in which i prototype the assembly function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
void clrscr(void);
extern char _columns, _rows;
extern void _curpos(char _columns, char _rows);
void arcradius() {
    float w;
    float h;
    float radi = w / 2.0;
    float value;
    clrscr();

  ...

_curpos(20,40);
getch();
arcradius();

}
```

The issue im having is that my C program is not giving the assembly function the right arguments, in my C file i use _curpos(20,40) but it doesn't use the values in the parentheses. Instead it uses some garbage number from the previous scanf(); input.

Is there something im mis-declaring, prototyping incorrectly, or forgot?

I'm using OpenWatcom and MASM 6.11.

Thanks, Noah "MadDog" Buzelli

EDIT:
Here is the fixed assembly function

```
;  Im failing super hard at writing this
;  Function.
.MODEL small
.DATA?
.DATA
curpos PROTO C _columns:BYTE, _rows:BYTE
.CODE
public curpos
curpos PROC  C _columns:BYTE, _rows:BYTE
    push     bx
    mov dh, BYTE PTR _columns
    mov dl, BYTE PTR _rows
    mov     bh, 0
    mov     ah, 2
    int 10h
    pop     bx
    ret 4
curpos ENDP
END
```

And here is my C prototype

```
extern void __stdcall curpos(char columns, char rows);
```

Thank you Mgetz :)

Comment: Does it matter that in the assembly, all I see is `curpos_` but in your C code you are calling `_curpos`?

Comment: What calling-conventions does the C compiler have (register, stack, something else)? And it doesn't matter if you name arguments the same as variables, they will still be different.

Comment: `cdecl` calling convention functions do not have decorators so you call it with the exact name. But you should specify the convection in your C code.

Comment: And considering the code and compiler used, I assume you're targeting an old 16-bit DOS platform? You might want to [edit] your question to add corresponding tags. It makes it easier for the right people who can help you to find the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude looks to be openwatcom which is [`__stdcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) by default.

Comment: Yes, i am targeting DOS as my platform, I think I'm calling the function correctly, i do not get any compiler errors or linker errors, it DOES move the cursor but it doesn't use the numbers in the parantheses, before i called _curpos(); i did a scanf("%f", &h); and it seems to move the cursor based off of that value instead.

Comment: @MadDog386 either you need to have your assembly conform to a specified calling convention (which you need to add to the C prototype) or you need to tell open watcom what to do. I'd suggest just sticking to `__stdcall` as that's what openwatcom expects. But specify that in the code anyway.

Comment: @Mgetz Any way you can give me a small example? I would hugely appreciate it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you need to specify the [Calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) for the assembly method. By default open watcom uses `__stdcall`

So it should look something like this:

```c
extern void __stdcall curpos(char _columns, char _rows);
```

This asm is probably right, but untested.  We're doing everything manually, not relying on MASM's magic to set up BP and calculate the position of args on the stack.

```
_columns$ = 4                                       ; size = 1
_rows$ = 6         ; offsets relative to the frame pointer
                   ; saved-BP at [bp+0], ret addr at [bp+2], first arg at [bp+4]
_curpos@4 PROC                                      ; COMDAT
        push    bp
        mov     bp, sp        ; for access to args on the stack, [sp] isn't valid
        push    bx            ; save/restore the caller's BX
        mov     dh, BYTE PTR _columns$[bp]
        mov     dl, BYTE PTR _rows$[bp]
        mov     bh, 0         ; page=0
        mov     ah, 2
        int     10h           ; int 10h / AH=2 - BIOS Set cursor position   
        pop     bx
        pop     bp          ; no  mov sp,bp  needed, SP is already good
        ret     4           ; pop ret addr, then SP+=4
_curpos@4 ENDP
```

For what it's worth it may be better to use inline assembly for this instead of doing a full implementation in asm. If you use inline asm the compiler takes care of all of this, you just have to get the inputs into registers, not write code that returns.

Comment: Thank you, this is what ended up working for me
`extern void __stdcall curpos(char columns, char rows);` as my prototype in my C file

Comment: @MadDog386 just curious... did I get the stack alignment right?

Comment: Im not sure, if i could properly paste my code into the comment, i added a pop bp and pop sp at the end of my assembly function and it seemed to work combined with your __stdcall

Comment: @MadDog386 your assembly doesn't actually follow the calling convention is my concern. The version in my answer should. Note the final version in my answer uses 6 bytes of stack, and it's all handled implicitly via the `push`/`pop` and `ret` inst. Failing to do things correctly may result in stack corruption.

Comment: I added my assembly code to the end of my question at the top of the page, maybe you can point it out cause i"m pretty new to assembly overall.

Comment: @MadDog386 you shouldn't need those two final instructions. You do need to `push bx` though as it's *callee save* you then need to `pop bx` before the `ret 4` and it's `ret 4` because your parameters take up 4 bytes on the stack. I am assuming 16bit...

Comment: I did the changes you had stated and it still works, I'll assume your method is bug free and my old one may possibly have been able to cause bugs.

Thank you for all your information and tips. I don't think i would have figured this out without your help. I consider this answered.

Comment: @MadDog386 yours may have worked depending on a lot of other things, but it was almost certainly corrupting the stack by adding too much back to the stack pointer on the return. That means whatever was calling it could be corrupted and that's bad. It causes very subtle and painful failures

Comment: Note that `_columns_$[sp]` isn't a valid addressing mode; 16-bit addressing modes can only use subsets of  BX|BP + SI|DI + const, so SP isn't allowed as part of the addressing mode.  That's why 16-bit code that wants random access to the stack basically always sets up BP as a frame pointer, unlike 32 / 64-bit code where `-fomit-frame-pointer` is common for modern optimizing compilers.  `_columns_$[esp]` would be legal (on a 386 in 16-bit mode), but would be different with non-zero upper bytes of ESP.

Comment: I guess @MadDog386 didn't say they used this asm, just the prototype, leaving arg access to MASM's magic to insert instructions into your code to set up BP and restore it before `ret 4`.  If you look at disassembly, you'll see those extra instructions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did use the BYTE PTR Var from his asm code. Without that i don't think it was getting the (char) numbers i was passing to it.

Comment: @MadDog386: You used `_columns$ = 4` /  `mov  dh, BYTE PTR _columns_$[sp]` from this answer?  Or you used `mov dh, BYTE PTR columns` from your own question, *not* like this answer?  The difference is the `[sp]` part of the addressing mode which is not encodeable in machine code.  Your `columns_:BYTE` declaration should imply byte operand-size, and definitely loading into a byte register means you're loading a byte if it assembles at all.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes the code at the bottom of my question is the one i used that works, i initially had it as `mov    dh, columns` but it wouldn't take my numbers from `curpos(x,y);` until i changed it to `mov    dh, BYTE PTR columns`

Comment: @PeterCordes figured, you're free to edit it to be correct. Godbolt doesn't have openwatcom so it was very difficult to test. 

Comment: Edited.  Still untested, but I'm pretty sure that's correct unless an assembler munges it.  I think your offsets relative to SP were correct before, given the one `push bx`.  Only problem was the illegal addressing mode involving `[sp]`.